# Updating many rows with sequelize inside a loop

Tags: mysql, asynchronous, redis, sequelize.js

I have an array of data from the payload, and i like to loop through the data and update it into the database, after all data was updated i want to update the cache data that i get from redis

**The payload**

```
"data": [
    {
        "surveyFieldId": 384471,
        "answer": "new answer"
    },
    {
        "surveyFieldId": 384472,
        "answer": "new answer"
    }
]
```

**Update method**

```
async updateDataSurveyField (dataSurveyId, { surveyFieldId, answer, needRevision }) {
let params = {
  answer
};

let DataSurveyField = await this.db.DataSurveyField.update(params, {
  where: {
    dataSurveyId,
    surveyFieldId
  }
});

return DataSurveyField;
```

}

**Loop and update cache**

```
if (data) {
      for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
        await this.updateDataSurveyField(object.id, data[index], method);
      }
    }

await updateCacheReport({
        db: this.db,
        key: report.uuid
      });
```

The updateCache method is querying the data from the database again, and insert it to redis.

My problem is the updateCache method was run when the update loop is not completed yet, so if i send 5 answer only 2 or 3 data was updated to the cache.Is there any way i can make sure the whole answer is update first then update the cache ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enforce the wait for all the async calls. Something like:

```
Promise.all(
    data.map(
        item => this.updateDataSurveyField(object.id, data[index], method)
    )
).then(surveyFields => {
  await updateCacheReport({
        db: this.db,
        key: report.uuid
      });
})
```

See [How to make promise.all wait for nested promise.all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36545464/how-to-make-promise-all-wait-for-nested-promise-all) to get a feeling of the Promise pattern.